# Nginx - proxy_pass root allow access only for specific IP

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to allow traffic only from `10.10.10.94`.

If I browse:

`http://IP/api:5006` (from any machine other than allow), I'm getting `access denied` and it works as it should.

`http://IP:5007` I get web page (although no data shown in WEB page - page should some graphs from allowed host only).

**PROBLEM:**

For `/api` location access works fine, it's allowed only from allowed IP, but for `/` no restrictions, can access from any IP.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    client_max_body_size 16M;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 http2 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;

  server_name example.com;
  client_max_body_size 16M;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/star.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/star.key;

  location / {

      allow 10.10.10.94;
      deny 10.10.0.0/16;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5007/;
  }
  location /api/ {

       allow 10.10.10.94;
      deny 10.10.0.0/16;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5006/;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this location:

```
  location / {
      allow 10.10.10.94/32;
      deny all;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5007/;
  }
  location /api/ {
      allow 10.10.10.94/32;
      deny all;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5006/;
  }
```

Comment: @scripter this module active in default configuration of the nginx. they are both identical, in any other options will be used `/`, config is valid. Are you sure you have a problem?

Comment: no, it's not, in default nginx configuration all is commented out, i'm using different conf file for each web site,   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
is active in default conf file.

Comment: @scripter you cannot comment it out. module `ngx_http_access_module` is enable by default inside nginx.

Comment: that line is not present in my nginx config,nginx version: nginx/1.12.2, for /api loocation access works as expected, but for / no restrictions

Comment: @scripter yes, this is default module, therefore it is not listed in `nginx -V`. You config is valid.